# How to find and replace contents of a bracket inside notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large file with content inside every bracket. This is not at the beginning of the line.

```
1. Atmos-phere (7800)
2. Atmospheric composition (90100)
3.Air quality (10110)
4. Atmospheric chemistry and composition (889s120)
5.Atmospheric particulates (10678130)
```

I need to do the following

1. Replace the entire content, get rid of line numbers
   `1.Atmosphere (10000)` to plain `Atmosphere`
2. Delete the line numbers as well 
   `1.Atmosphere (10000)` to plain `Atmosphere`
3. make it a hyperlink
   `1.Atmosphere (10000)` to plain `<a href="http://blahqd.com/Atmosphere.htm">linky study</a>`
4. [*I added/Edit*] Extract the words into a new file, where we get a simple list of key words. Can you also please explain the numbers *in replace the \1\2, and escape on some characters*

   1. Each set of key words is a new line
      `Atmospheric`
      `Atmospheric composition`
      `Air quality`
   2. Each set is a on one line separated by one space and commas
      `Atmospheric, Atmospheric composition, Air quality`

I tried find with regex like so, `\(*\)` it finds the brackets, but dont know how to replace this, and where to put the replace, and what variable holds the replacement value.

Comment: It may be better to create a new question rather than adding more bits on to your original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is mine exression for notepad `([0-9(). ]*)(.*)(\s\()(.*)`

1. You need split your search in groups

   1. `([0-9. ]*)` numbers, spaces and dots combination in 0 or more times
   2. `(.*)` everything till next expression
   3. `(\s\()` space and opening parenthesis
   4. `(.*)` everything else
2. In replace box - for practicing if you place

   2. `\1\2\3\4` this do nothing :) just print all groups from above from **1.1** to **1.4**
   3. `\2` this way you get only **1.2** group
   4. `new_thing\2new_thing` adds your text before and after group
   5. `<a href=blah.com/\2.html>linky study</a>` so now your text is added - spaces between words can be problematic when creating link - so another expression need to be made to replace all spaces in link to i.e. `_`
   6. If you need add backslash as text (or other special sign used by regex) it must be escaped so you put `\\` for backslash or `\$` for dolar sign

Want more tune - `<a href=blah.com/\2.html>\2</a>` add again **1.2** group - or use whichever you want

On the screenshot you can see how I use it (I had found and replaced one line)
[image]

Ok and then we have case 4.2 with colon at the end so simply add colon after extracted section:

change replace from `\2` to `\2,`

Now you need join it so simplest way is to **Edit->Line Operations->Join Lines**
but if you want to be real pro switch to `Extended mode` (just above `Regular expression` mode in `Replace` window) and Find `\r\n` and replace with space.

Removing line endings can differ in some cases but this is another story - for now I assume that you using windows since Notepad++ is windows tool and line endings are in windows style :)

Comment: Thanks for the broken down explanation, I was trying to break it down and understand like you said. But when I tried in Notepad, notepad says "could not find any text matching ([0-9(). ]?)(.\*)(\s\()(.*)"

Comment: Hey man - you omitted escape in open parenthesis in (\s\() so it should look (\s\\() and another fix is that I replaced ? to * in first expression

Comment: You have the most answers.

Comment: You have the most answers. `You solved) Scenario 2 and 4.1`. Your explanation was easier to follow. However, when I put \2 in replace, it gives me funky ouput - `S(` on every line.

Comment: Try it now - I added some further explanations

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30672/discussion-between-abrasadera-and-aroos)

Answer (score 8):

The following regex should do the job: `\d+\.\s*(.*?)\s*\(.*?\)`.

And the replacement: `<a href=example.com\\\1.htm>\1</a>`.

**Explanation:**

- `\d+` : Match a digit 0 or more times.
- `\.` : Match a dot.
- `\s*` : Match spaces 0 or more times.
- `(.*?)` : Group and match everything until `(` found.
- `\s*` : Match spaces 0 or more times.
- `\(.*?\)` : Match parenthesis and what's between it.

The replacement part is simple since `\1` is referring to the matching group.

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iX1bY5).**

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `^\d+\.(.*) \(\w+\)$` with `<a href=blah.com\\\1.htm>linky study</a>`.

The `^\d+.` removes the leading number and dot. The `(.*)` collects the words. Then there is a single space. The `\(\w+\)$` matches the final number in brackets.

Update for the added Q4.

Regular expressions capture things written between round brackets `(` and `)`. Brackets that are to be found in the text being searched must be escaped as `\(` and `\)`. In the replacement expression the `\1` and `\2` etc are replaced by the corresponding capture expression. So a search expression such as `Z(\d+)X([aeiou]+)Y` might match `Z29XeieiY` then the replacement expression `P\2Q\1R` would insert `PeieiQ29R`. In the search at the top of this answer there is one capture, the `(.)` captures or collects the words and then the `\1` inserts the captured words into the replacement text.

Comment: Beside numbers OP have also characters inside brackets.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for spotting that. Changed `\(\d+\)$` to `\(\w+\)$`.